# How to make this like query more faster?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

Currently below query takes 1 sec with 100 data in PostgreSQL.It maybe takes a long time when data comes in a bunch so how can I make this query faster?

**Query:**

```
select distinct u.firstname,u.lastname,u.email,u.profile_pic
from user u
where (lower (u.firstname) like '%ab%'
       or lower(u.email) like  '%ab%'   
       or lower(u.lastname) like '%ab%' )
  and u.id != 2 
  and u.active = true;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user16320675 Yeah, We are using this query in JPQL.

Comment: http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's great. Now it takes time in msec.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works well in the local PostgreSQL DB but in the server's PostgreSQL DB it takes reverse effect. At first, it takes `420 msec`, and after making pg_trgm Extension and index, it takes `1 sec 599 msec`. Have you any idea why this happens?

Comment: It's a table scan. You can't really do anything beyond a covering index.

Answer (score 1):

I have only 2 recomendations for you:

1. When you are using functions on the fields in were conditions, so recommended to create an expression index (function-based index), if-else your DB can not use indexes. For your query recommended creating `lower(lastname)` index instead of `lastname` index (and for firstname and email fields)
2. For using `like '%xxx%'` your DB can not use indexes for this field. For using indexes you must write `like 'xxx%'`. If you needed to use only '%xx%' then recommended using `Full-Text Search` modules on DB.
   There are many samples and documentation on the Internet about "How to enable `Full-Text Search` on PostgreSQL".

**In addition, you do not need anything else.**